# Does $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ converges implies $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I know that the following statement is true (where $a$ always denote a real number):

> Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=a$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ converges to $a$.

The proof of this statement is simple, it suffices to notice that
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}\le\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}\le\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}.$$

What about the converse statement? Does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=a$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=a$? I think it is not true, but I can't find a counter-example. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take the constant sequence $a_n =0$

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum That's not a counterexample. Both limits are $10$.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum The question isn't about the convergence of the underlying sequence $a_n$, it's about the convergence of the ratio and root sequences. In your example, both the root and ratio sequence converge to the value 10.

Comment: @jjagmath The ratio test, where this kind of sequence comes up, usually requires the sequence to be nonzero.

Comment: Oops, I misread the question.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes. And my example shows why the root test is strictly stronger than the ratio test. You can't even apply the ratio test for that sequence.

Comment: You can make the ratios unbounded and not bounded away from $0$ while the root test is effective: $n^{(-1)^n}.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $a_n=1$ for $n$ even and $2$ for $n$ odd. Then $a_n^{1/n} \to 1$ but $\frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n}$ oscillates.